# Align multiple equations

Tags: equations, align

I would like to align multiple equations below each other. However, I cannot figure out how I should code this. I'm using the following  preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


%comments
%pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex

\usepackage{titling}
    \setlength{\droptitle}{-12cm}

\usepackage{graphics, float}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{siunitx}   %allows SI units by using \SI{unit} 
\usepackage{amsmath}   %allows \begin{equation} \end{equation}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}     %allows you to widen or shorten the page width from the left or the right.
```

For `F_{hkl}` I would like to align the equations below. The equal sign of the second equation should be placed right below the equal sign in the first equation. Can someone help me figuring this out?

I am now using the following code, but I am not satisfied with it yet.

```
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{F_{hkl}} = \mathrm{f_{j}} 
( \operatorname{e} ^ {2\pi \cdot i (h\cdot0 + k\cdot0 + l\cdot0)} + 
\operatorname{e} ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot0)} + 
\operatorname{e} ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot0 + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} + 
\operatorname{e} ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot0 + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} )
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{F_{hkl}} = \mathrm{f_{j}} 
( \operatorname{e} ^ {2\pi i \cdot 0} + 
\operatorname{e} ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} } + 
\operatorname{e} ^ {2\pi  i (k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} + 
\operatorname{e} ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} )
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: You should use the `align*` environment provided by `amsmath`, not two `equation*` environments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This type of alignment is provided out-of-the-box using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ee}{\mathrm{e}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \mathrm{F_{hkl}} = \mathrm{f_{j}} 
  ( \ee ^ {2\pi \cdot i (h\cdot0 + k\cdot0 + l\cdot0)} + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot0)} + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot0 + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot0 + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} )
\]

\[
  \mathrm{F_{hkl}} = \mathrm{f_{j}} 
  ( \ee ^ {2\pi i \cdot 0} + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} } + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} )
\]

\begin{align*}
  \mathrm{F_{hkl}} &= \mathrm{f_{j}} 
  ( \ee ^ {2\pi \cdot i (h\cdot0 + k\cdot0 + l\cdot0)} + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot0)} + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot0 + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot0 + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} ) \\
  \mathrm{F_{hkl}} &= \mathrm{f_{j}} 
  ( \ee ^ {2\pi i \cdot 0} + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} } + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} + 
  \ee ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} )
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Alignments are ensured using `&=`.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using an `align*` environment to align the two equations on their `=` symbols, you may want to look into using the `mathastext` package to save yourself from having to type lots and lots of `\mathrm` "wrapper" statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
F_{hkl} &= f_{j} \bigl(
e ^ {2\pi \cdot i (h\cdot0 + k\cdot0 + l\cdot0)} + 
e ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot0)} + 
e ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot0 + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} + 
e ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot0 + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} \bigr)\\
F_{hkl} &= f_{j} \bigl(
e ^ {2\pi i \cdot 0} + 
e ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + k\cdot\frac{1}{2} } + 
e ^ {2\pi  i (k\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} + 
e ^ {2\pi  i (h\cdot\frac{1}{2} + l\cdot\frac{1}{2})} \bigr)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```